# MS Word 2016 - TOC - Need to add a letter (A, B, etc.) suffix to chapter referene

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, table-of-contents

I have a Word 2016 .docx that contains a single chapter of a larger document. For two of the chapters I need a letter suffix for the chapter number (i.e. 3A, 3B). I have succeeded in doing this in the multi-level list so that the styles work correctly for paragraph numbering, but I cannot figure out how to get my TOC to list the chapter reference so that it includes the chapter prefix correctly (i.e. 3A-1, 3A-2). Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my tests, you can Define New Multi-level List and link level to style to Heading 1~3 as following:

Level 1:

[image]

Level 2:

[image]

Level 3:

[image]

Apply it to your content and insert ToC:

[image]